# How can I bind an array of data to html table using Spring boot REST apllication and not by Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot REST application, in which one of the REST API sends mail to the respective users.

I have designed a mailer template in Html and my rest API has data in an array which I am binding to an Html table using  and  tags.

How can I bind an array of data to Html table using Spring Boot REST application and not by Spring MVC

```
1. HTML code

    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 20px 18px 0; color: #888686; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Open Sans';">
                            <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th
                                            style="padding: 8px 20px; border: 1px solid #eeeeee; background: #ffffff; color: #888686; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Open Sans'; width: 35%;">
                                            DATE</th>
                                            <th
                                            style="padding: 8px 20px; border: 1px solid #eeeeee; background: #ffffff; color: #888686; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Open Sans'; width: 35%;">
                                            AVAILABILITY</th>
                                            <th
                                            style="padding: 8px 20px; border: 1px solid #eeeeee; background: #ffffff; color: #888686; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Open Sans'; width: 35%;">
                                            WORK START TIME</th>
                                             <th
                                            style="padding: 8px 20px; border: 1px solid #eeeeee; background: #ffffff; color: #888686; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Open Sans'; width: 35%;">
                                            WORK END TIME</th>
                                             <th
                                            style="padding: 8px 20px; border: 1px solid #eeeeee; background: #ffffff; color: #888686; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Open Sans'; width: 35%;">
                                            BREAK START TIME</th>
                                             <th
                                            style="padding: 8px 20px; border: 1px solid #eeeeee; background: #ffffff; color: #888686; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Open Sans'; width: 35%;">
                                            BREAK END TIME</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <c:forEach var="oldList" items="${scheduleDetailsOld}">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding: 8px 20px; border: 1px solid #eeeeee; background: #ffffff; color: #888686; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Open Sans'; width: 35%;">${oldList.day}</td>
                                        <td style="padding: 8px 20px; border: 1px solid #eeeeee; background: #ffffff; color: #888686; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Open Sans'; width: 35%;">${oldList.availability}</td>
                                        <td style="padding: 8px 20px; border: 1px solid #eeeeee; background: #ffffff; color: #888686; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Open Sans'; width: 35%;">${oldList.workStartTime}</td>
                                        <td style="padding: 8px 20px; border: 1px solid #eeeeee; background: #ffffff; color: #888686; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Open Sans'; width: 35%;">${oldList.workEndTime}</td>
                                        <td style="padding: 8px 20px; border: 1px solid #eeeeee; background: #ffffff; color: #888686; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Open Sans'; width: 35%;">${oldList.breakStartTime}</td>
                                        <td style="padding: 8px 20px; border: 1px solid #eeeeee; background: #ffffff; color: #888686; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Open Sans'; width: 35%;">${oldList.breakEndTime}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

2.email sender method

public void shiftUpdatedMailForEditor(Staff staff) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
                values.put("getName", staff.getName());
                values.put("getSubject", "Work schedule details have been modified.");
                mailerService.sendStaffShiftUpdatedForEditorEmail(values, staff.getEmail());
            } catch (PaperTrueException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
    }

3. get HTML temlate service

    protected void sendStaffShiftUpdatedForEditorEmail(Map<String, String> valuesMap, String receiverEmail)
                throws PaperTrueJavaException {
            // concerned Editor (receiverEmail)
            System.out.println("Inside sendStaffShiftUpdatedForEditorEmail");
            mailer.sendMail("xyz@gmail.com", "xyz@gmail.com", valuesMap.get("getSubject"),
                    formatHtml(getHTMLBody(HtmlTemplateURL), valuesMap));
        }

4. here is my controller
    
    @PostMapping("/update-schedule-details")
                public ResponseEntity<StatusResponse> updateScheduleDetails(@Valid @RequestBody addScheduleDetailsBody body,
                        Model model) {
                    StatusResponse statusResponse = new StatusResponse();
                    try {
                        util.isStaffLoggedIn(request, response, List.of(StaffRole.EDITOR, StaffRole.HR_MANAGER));
                        Iterator<AddScheduleDetails> iterator = body.getScheduleDetails().iterator();
                        ArrayList<ScheduleDetails> scheduleDetailsNew = new ArrayList<ScheduleDetails>();
                    ArrayList<ScheduleDetails> scheduleDetailsEarlier = new ArrayList<ScheduleDetails>();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        AddScheduleDetails addScheduleDetails = (AddScheduleDetails) iterator.next();
                        if (scheduleDetailsService.getShift(new Date(addScheduleDetails.getDay()),
                                addScheduleDetails.getEditorId())) {
                            addScheduleDetails(addScheduleDetails);
                        } else {
                            scheduleDetailsEarlier = updateScheduleDetails(addScheduleDetails, scheduleDetailsEarlier);
                        }
                        ScheduleDetails scheduleDetails = scheduleDetailsService.get(new Date(addScheduleDetails.getDay()),
                                addScheduleDetails.getEditorId());
                        scheduleDetailsNew.add(scheduleDetails);
                    }
                    model.addAttribute("scheduleDetailsOld", scheduleDetailsEarlier);
                    model.addAttribute("scheduleDetailsNew", scheduleDetailsNew);
                        emailSender.shiftUpdatedMailForEditor(util.getLoggedInStaff(request));
                        statusResponse.setStatus(new Status("Editor Schedule Details Updated Successfully"));
                    } catch (PaperTrueException e) {
                        util.logException(e, LogType.GET_JOBS);
                        statusResponse.setStatus(new Status(e.getCode(), e.getMessage()));
                    }
                    return ResponseEntity.ok(statusResponse);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use some standard library like Datatables, it will be much easier. 
 See this,
https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

This way, you can just send json data from your REST API in response

Comment: but I am using an HTML template to send mail to a user and In that template, I have to pass ArrayList data in the table